# How to use union type as function parameter

Tags: typescript, union-types

I the example below I have created a union type (string or number). Then I have created a function signature which should accept as input a string or number. But now I cannot use this function definition

```
type AB = string | number

type X = (inp: AB) => void;

const x: X = (inp: number) => { console.log('ok')}; // <-- ERROR
const y: X  = (inp: string) => { console.log('ok')}; // <- ERROR
```

Because the constants x and y have errors

[image]

[UPDATED DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFAzsATgSwHYHMoA%20U2ArgLYBGE6AUDaJFABoA8AKlBAB7ATYAmKWHAB8SKAAocYAFxQ2ASiRiAbgHtM-ANx0AxmuxooXOa1KVqY5NOVQA3lH2G1AGwgA6F2twSA5GoBrXwUAXx0nIxBTFjQsPDFxG0QxBwjXDy8ffyDQnRoAenyoADkAUQB1KABaGtqavQMjPnIoAC97Y3FfLl8AGigQLpBfMLoGaABZEDZwCCFkBwBtAAUoHDaAXWj4MRCGw2AoNQoAKzkpmch5%20xooO%20M5KWxZVAwcXCVkjrS3T28-YAAC0wQhBUAAhq84vg%20mtnkoQr1bvcopJpHJzFR0J8Uo5Guk-lkgWCwZDMdQoLDpAiaKM6EA)

The type `AB` can change, more types can be added, so I would be nice if I could use it in defining type `X` and then create implementation for each type defined in `AB`. But how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with `X`, you won't even need to type the argument in the implementations:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=10&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFAzsATgSwHYHMoA+U2ArgLYBGE6A3AFCiRQAaAPACpQQAewE2AExSw4APiRQAFDjAAuKOwCUScQDcA9pgH06AY3XY0UbvLalK1ccmnYwyxOIDedKFBlQA9B+Lkq6OgC+OvqGwFAgpqxoWHhWUjL2Ti5utp7e0Ti4gfRAA)

```ts
type AB = string | number;
type X<T extends AB> = (inp: T) => void;

const x: X<number> = (inp) => {
  inp // number
};

const y: X<string> = (inp) => {
  inp // string
};
```

---

Edit: Response to new question:

> Note that idiomatically-named [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) use [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

See comments in code:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAECEEMGcFNQC4E8AOtoC4BQXgCo8tQ9QAxAJwHsBbUAbQBEBLaBcpgIwFcEmA3eAGNKAOwAmTXqMgAbRKnQBdABQALBAhSYQAdz0A6ZGmiD2KBDMgiA5vsrlrwMZUHRgqq2I6VKAa2DksDKwMLAAtCKUCOjARuimTOZhAExhABz66tQyAMQSrOzcvAJhwuKSTNIyYXHQAJTYxEQkAHyg+h1WoEwirFa8kFIioJQAZqAABgAqoLAAHtHi0KAAqqAA-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-w0Cg9xjac4r-t1sBlHCIF+rA4GjAKghDA2sjNoMsAsZtry5jMnZLKAyH2GhGGgFhhSRnhogEUmRHeYVZEUZRyh8LIXB7aAUwNBDt4FoEFZVidMhg2u344CDMhndEl1HcoN6caA3FqXxSkCXWQmmaIULmRJUkyaocnLApbUqS5oDft+dQpfgBbabzfN8wAekLwsi6LYvixLktSxLWAplQaDkMgH5ft0yzUCw0A9NYqnyGg4qgAAouQVCOcoySOgALAArPieDBlg6OYxdCFXbjHF6UT6Va8ZwmU6JFm09Zqt3F7ynOWprkFrpBP6aAZrBFYPsU70-s01Z9M2YzdkdU5qnqWz0rc9pAtYFMNYPoTvFxz4CciMZjbNg+wcDfCmvWCIkAcMEiCULr8AV8OxMZaTE4Nk2Yg0gTg-Z9QDn1+PdQPvrRsmwT5vJMktvBhz1GU7RCHJO+jtiOd2MIG72n45XQ-e2TJlmWJad0wzIfM+H+eaVHHtV9l5BJw-Ad04vwUr-XOrNP47w8nlAqWYWLJACvlMq0QKoRXGDVZIMVnyNSSlzVqJNcrwBgUVeCyQSqIL+uVMKqCookPqnFBKOCWozwcl1MAgBeDcALI7WAgA)

```ts
// Base types:

/**
 * From [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types):
 *
 * > ...an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with
 * > the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as
 * > `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`.
 *
 * For `T extends unknown ? ...`, see also:
 * https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#example-3
 */
type DistributeUnionToFirstParamInFn<
  U,
  FnReturnType = void,
> = U extends unknown ? ((_: U) => FnReturnType) : never;

type AB = string | number;
const enum Z { X = 'x', Y = 'y'};

// First example:

type MyObj = Record<Z, DistributeUnionToFirstParamInFn<AB>>;

const obj1: MyObj = {
  x: (inp: string) => { console.log('this is a string ', inp) },
  y: (inp: number) => { console.log('this is a number ', inp) },
};

type ParamInObj1X = Parameters<typeof obj1['x']>[0]; // string | number
type ParamInObj1Y = Parameters<typeof obj1['y']>[0]; // string | number

// So, not quite what you want. Compare with...
//Second example:

function validateObject <T extends Record<Z, DistributeUnionToFirstParamInFn<AB>>>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}

validateObject({x: (inp: string) => { console.log('this is a string ', inp) }}); /*
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Property 'y' is missing in type... Error (2345) */

validateObject({
  x: (inp: string) => { console.log('this is a string ', inp) },
  y: (inp: boolean) => { console.log('this is a number ', inp) }, /*
  ^
Type '(inp: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '((_: string) => void) | ((_: number) => void)'... Error (2322) */
});

const obj2 = validateObject({
  x: (inp: string) => { console.log('this is a string ', inp) },
  y: (inp: number) => { console.log('this is a number ', inp) },
});

type ParamInObj2X = Parameters<typeof obj2['x']>[0]; // string
type ParamInObj2Y = Parameters<typeof obj2['y']>[0]; // number

//
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I noticed that in my case I also have an intermediate type which looks like this: `type MyTypes = { [P in z]: X<AB >}` I've updated the demo example in my post (I couldn't copy the url in here) I'm unable to use your solution in this almost exact identical situation. Can you have a look to see if something I did is wrong?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I don’t see any revisions to your question.

Comment: sorry. I still needed to hit save :) Just did that!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri You've now expanded the scope of your question after I answered it (see [scope creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep)). I'm happy to respond to your new question in order for you to learn (see my updated answer), but if you need new information, you should ask a new, independent question (so that you follow the network policy of not modifying a question to change its meaning).

Comment: Thanks. I skipped that requirement in my question, because I thought it was irrelevant. But it makes it super complex :) I will have to study on this one