# How to define a generic function in an interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70741721/14887783) to define a function with a union type:

```js
type ValueType = number[] | string[] | number | string

type X<T extends ValueType> = (inp: T) => void;

const x: X<number> = (inp) => {
  inp // number
};

const y: X<string> = (inp) => {
  inp // string
};
```

But when I use it I get an error:

```js
type ValueType = number[] | string[] | number | string

interface I1<X>{
  setValue: <X extends ValueType>(value: X) => void
}

const i1: I1<number> = {
  setValue: (value: number) => {
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

Compiler prompt information:

```
TS2322: Type '(value: number) => void' is not assignable to type '<X extends ValueType>(value: X) => void'.   
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.     
Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'number'.       
Type 'ValueType' is not assignable to type 'number'.         
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.  
test.ts(23, 3): The expected type comes from property 'setValue' which is declared here on type 'I1<number>'
```

What am I doing wrong, it seems to me that these two pieces of code are not different.

Comment: what is `ValueType`?

Comment: @RobertRendell sorry, I miss it, I have added the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition of `interface I1<X>`, you are not using the type parameter `X`.

When you define method `setValue<X>` within `I1<X>`, you're not using the existing `X` type. Instead you're declaring a separate type parameter for the method, which also happens to be called `X`.

Easy fix – remove the type parameter from the method:

```js
type ValueType = number[] | string[] | number | string

interface I1<X extends ValueType>{
  setValue: (value: X) => void
}

const i1: I1<number> = {
  /* Bonus: TS will infer the type of `value` for you here */
  setValue: (value) => {
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigOyQWwCMIAnAbQF0oAfKAZ2BIEscBzSm3A4kzh5tgChBLYKQBmcAMbQAkgEYAPAA0oEAB5icAEzqxEKdJAB8Ab0FR6EYPGQQAXFAAUANwMOoygJRRMxqC4A9kzaggC+wlKBOAxQTPKOCop4RKT+2OaWAPQAVFAAQtFIdI6oAMpQAO5MCAhxOOKkUMAAFtCgkFCB4lAABm52vVDigbwggUhQbSTQOVkWVjbujq7uPn5QmZZQUTGBCBAAdAiBrKt2XgsRYUA)

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
interface I1<X extends ValueType>{
  setValue: (value: X) => void
}
```

Instead of

```
interface I1<X>{
  setValue: <X extends ValueType>(value: X) => void
}
```